# ES6 modules - best approach for creating an immutable service

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, ecmascript-6, service, es6-modules

I'm using the following approach for creating a singleton-like service in my application:

**myService.js**:

```js
let myService = {};

myService.doSomething = function() {
    //doing something
};

export {myService};
```

**usage in other module**:

```js
import {myService} from 'myService.js'

myService.doSomething();

export {myService};
```

Generally this works fine, but the problem is that it's possible to modify the service in a module that is importing it:

```js
import {myService} from 'myService.js'

myService.doSomething = function() {
    //do something different
};

export {myService};
```

This is not desireable for a singleton-service, it should be immutable.

How can immutability can be achieved? Does anybody have a completely different/better approach for creating immutable services as ES6 modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi we can achieve by using `Object.freeze` method. i have created one demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wfhq4c kindly check mozilla dev website.

you can also refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze

Answer (score 1):

You can create a private function in `myService`. Also create a default function `pub` in myservice and call `doSomething` from this default function.

Then in the other file when you will call myService it will give access to only default function

```
let myService = {}
myService.doSomething = function() {
  console.log('Test');
  return 'myservice doSomething executed'
};
export function pub() {
  return myService.doSomething()
}


import * as test from './myService'
console.log(test.pub());
```

Please check console of this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7qu6bm)